# How to pass an enum to a parent class's static function to instantiate a child class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, inheritance, constructor

I have a 3 classes, `ParentClass`,`ClassA`,`ClassB`. Both `ClassA` and `ClassB` are subclasses of `ParentClass`. I wanna try to create objects of type `ClassA` or `ClassB` using some kind of enumeration to identify a type, and then instantiate the object cast as the parent type. How can I do that dynamically? Please take a look at the code below, and the parts that say `//what do I put here?`. Thanks for reading!

```
enum ClassType
{
    ClassA,
    ClassB
};
public abstract class ParentClass
{


    public ParentClass()
    {
        //....
    }

    public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(ClassType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case ClassType.ClassA: 
                //What do I put here?
                break;
            case ClassType.ClassB:
                //What do I put here?
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class ClassA:ParentClass
{
    //....
}
public class ClassB:ParentClass
{
    //.......
}
```

Comment: I wonder why you have managed 99% but not the `new ClassA`/`new ClassB`(your own method-name suggests already the solution).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I took a 1 hour nap and I realised I posted the wrong question. Sorry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
public class ParentClass 
{
    public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(ClassType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case ClassType.ClassA: 
                return new ClassA();
                break;
            case ClassType.ClassB:
                return new ClassB();
                break;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public class ClassA:ParentClass
{
    //....
}
public class ClassB:ParentClass
{
    //.......
}
```

But, if you define default constructors on your subclasses, this is a lot simpler...

```
public class ParentClass 
{
    private static Dictionary<ClassType, Type> typesToCreate = ...

    // Generics are cool
    public static T GetNewObjectOfType<T>() where T : ParentClass
    {
        return (T)GetNewObjectOfType(typeof(T));
    }

    // Enums are fine too
    public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(ClassType type)
    {
        return GetNewObjectOfType(typesToCreate[type]);
    }

    // Most direct way to do this
    public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(Type type)
    {
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be done in a more complicated way by getting the name of the enum value and using reflection to instantiate, but it comes back to this.  Why not the simple straightforward way?  It performs better too.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin yes I think you are thinking what I am thinking. Can you please take a look at [this] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991673/c-how-to-pass-an-enum-to-a-parent-classs-static-function-to-instantiate-a-chi)

Comment: @p.s.w.g omg I just realize your answer is already correct for both questions. Thanks dude, good stuff

Comment: @blackeyedpea It seems you already have answers there.  It's fun and worthwhile to learn how to do clever things like this, but I would still consider the simplest solution.  I've just gone through some very complex processing code, and removing a few 'clever' uses of sped it up by a factor of 5.  Reflection is slow and is often used where it isn't needed.