# How to pass an enum to a parent class's static function to instantiate a child class Part II?

Tags: c#

This is a followup to a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990906/how-to-pass-an-enum-to-a-parent-classs-static-function-to-instantiate-a-child-c). There was a mistake in that question (I actually posted my current solution instead of the better one I'm looking for).

I have  3 classes, `ParentClass`,`ClassA`,`ClassB`. Both `ClassA` and `ClassB` are subclasses of `ParentClass`. I wanna try to create objects of type `ClassA` or `ClassB` using some kind of enumeration to identify a type, and then instantiate the object cast as the parent type. How can I do that dynamically? Please take a look at the code below, and the part that says `//what do I put here?`. Thanks for reading!

public enum ClassType
    {
        ClassA,
        ClassB
    };

```
public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<ClassType, Type> Types = 
        new Dictionary<ClassType, Type>{
            {ClassType.ClassA, typeof(ClassA) },
            {ClassType.ClassB, typeof(ClassB) }
        };

    public ParentClass()
    {
        //....
    }

    public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(ClassType type)
    {
        //What do I put here?
    }
}

public class ClassA:ParentClass
{
    //....
}
public class ClassB:ParentClass
{
    //.......
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%23]+factory+pattern

Comment: Any particular reason you can't use a generic factory?  SOAP/RPC?  If not, you can use Activator.CreateInstance() or compiled Lambda Expressions if speed is a factor.  If so, then you'll have to use a map of some sort, as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with the `Activator` class, especially if there aren't any arguments to the constructors:

`return Activator.CreateInstance(Types[type]);`

Answer (score 2):

To restate your question: you're looking for advice on how to code a static factory method.

I don't think you need a separate enumeration to accomplish this. This is a LINQPad script I threw together (EDIT: added static constants, demo creation using them)

```
void Main()
{
    var a = ParentClass.Create(typeof(ClassA));
    var b = ParentClass.Create(typeof(ClassB));
    var c = ParentClass.Create(ParentClass.ClassAType);
    a.Dump();
    b.Dump();
    c.Dump();
}


public abstract class ParentClass
{
    public static readonly Type ClassAType = typeof(ClassA); 
    public static readonly Type ClassBType = typeof(ClassB);
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
    protected ParentClass() {}

    public static ParentClass Create(Type typeToCreate)
    {
        // validate that type is derived from ParentClass
        return (ParentClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeToCreate);
    }
}

public class ClassA:ParentClass {
    public ClassA()
    {
        SomeProp = "ClassA~";
    }

}
public class ClassB:ParentClass
{
    public ClassB()
    {
        SomeProp = "ClassB~";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the previous question:

> Reflection is slow and is often used where it isn't needed

Activator.CreateInstance uses reflection to track down a parameter-less constructor.  To solve this problem - that isn't needed.  The parent class already knows all of the types it is responsible for creating.

---

One of the reasons to use a static factory method, is that there may be substantial work, or different kinds of work involved in creating the child classes.  I think if you beef up your map some, you'll have a easier time coding that static factory:

```
public static readonly Dictionary<ClassType, Func<ParentClass>> Types = 
    new Dictionary<ClassType, Func<ParentClass>>{
        {ClassType.ClassA, () => new ClassA(1, 2, 3) },
        {ClassType.ClassB, () => new ClassB("1") }
    };


public static ParentClass GetNewObjectOfType(ClassType type)
{
    Func<ParentClass> maker = Types[type];
    ParentClass result = maker();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I love that technique of using a dictionary of types mapped to delegates - it allows for some wonderful composition that allows for rich sets of rules built on simple logic